# Match array elements beginning with letters specified in another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, match, built-in

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => BCD
    [1] => ACE
    [2] => AHP
    [3] => BGH
    [4] => ART
    [5] => COT
    [6] => ARG
    [7] => BGT
)
```

I need to match all elements whose first letter is in the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => A
)
```

to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ACE
    [1] => AHP
    [2] => BGH
    [3] => ART
    [4] => ARG
    [5] => BGT
)
```

Short of looping through the whole array, how do I do this in PHP? Is there a built-in PHP array function for this or a combination of so? The order does not matter for both keys and values of the resulting array. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) for these operations:

```
$array = array('CBD', 'NHN', 'NHP', 'WHC', 'NND', 'CQN', 'WST', 'WVT');

$whitelist = array('W', 'N');

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($val) use ($whitelist) {
  // check if first letter is in the whitelist array
  if (in_array($val{0}, $whitelist)) {
    return $val;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => NHN
    [2] => NHP
    [3] => WHC
    [4] => NND
    [6] => WST
    [7] => WVT
)
```

Comment: i was able to make this work only when i took out `use ($whitelist)`.. hmm.. any idea why?

Comment: Hmm I am unable to execute it *without* the `use` keyword. I have PHP 5.3.5, maybe they changed the scope to global variables in more recent versions.